# Applying for a Standard Visitor visa from a Schengen country other than the Schengen country of residence

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, pakistani-citizens, standard-visitor-visas

I am a non EU citizen currently holding a valid resident permit of Luxembourg. As there is no UK visa application center in Luxembourg I have to apply from UK visa application center in Brussels, Belgium.
In the online uk visa application form question

> What permission do you have to be in Belgium?

What answer suits my case more as I am currently a resident of Luxembourg so I have authority to move freely among schengen states including Belgium and my resident permit in Luxembourg is till year 2020

Possible answer

(a) To choose "I have temporary visa" and mention that it ends at 2020

(b) **or** to choose "I do not have a visa and I am not a permanent resident" and state that I actually holds a resident permit of Luxembourg thus need no visa for travel to Belgium as both countries are in schengen region

Comment: Did you put in Luxembourg as your country of residence? It sounds strange that it would ask for your basis of being in a different country ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm If I got your comment right you are saying about putting the residential address as luxembourg then, Yes my residential address states that I am living in Luxembourg. I cannot apply from Luxembourg (as mentioned in question) so when I choose the application center at start of online application which is Belgium and continue filling the form he asks me this question under current status section.

Comment: It sounds like the form may be wrong.  What is the url you are using to complete the form?

Comment: this is the url of the visa form I am using,
[link](https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/uk-visit-visa)

Comment: I am applying through the new visa service as mentioned here [link](https://www.gov.uk/apply-uk-visa?utm_source=visa-application-form&utm_medium=internal-link&utm_campaign=svv-apply-visa)

Comment: It looks like a problem with the form, sounds like it's wrong.  I would use @HenningMakholm answer below in the meantime.

Comment: @GayotFow Just to make it clear, I would choose "I do not have a visa and I am not a permanent resident" and in comment part mention that "you're legally in Belgium based on your Luxembourg residence permit" because I think the temporary visa option is not valid in my case as I dont need visa to travel in Schengen zone. Your experienced suggestion is highly appreciated

Comment: Yes, but like I said, use the answer  @HenningMakholm he is an expert also.

Comment: @GayotFow For sure I will use the answer of "HenningMakholm" as he is also an expert(there is no argument about it), i just wanted to have another insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the Visa Application Centre in Belgium only processes visa applications for residents of Belgium. This is probably why the system assumed you were one after you chose to apply through Belgium.

https://www.gov.uk/find-a-visa-application-centre states that residents of Luxembourg should apply through *France*.

Comment: I believe that you can apply from any country in which UK Visas and
Immigration accept visa applications as stated here
[link](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/where-to-apply-ecb05/ecb5-where-to-apply-the-policy)

Comment: @Khan: In that case your answer should be that you're legally in Belgium based on your Luxembourg residence permit.

Comment: There are only two options either
_a) To choose "I have temporary visa" and mention that it ends at 2020
(b) or to choose "I do not have a visa and I am not a permanent resident" and state that I actually holds a resident permit of Luxembourg thus need no visa for travel to Belgium as both countries are in schengen region_

Answer (score 1):

Just to extend @Henning answer and for future reference to this question.

For my case as quoted in the question, I have placed the application from Brussels, Belgium and in the field

> What permission do you have to be in Belgium?

I have chosen *"I do not have a visa and I am not a permanent resident*" and stated that

*As I am a holder of valid resident and work permit of
Luxembourg which is valid till xx.xx.xx, I do not
need visa to enter into Belgium as its a part of
Schengen zone*

It worked for my particular case.